# How to visualize a layered graph (for GraphPlan planning algorithm)

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, visualization

I did a quick web search and having not found readily available (and library-provided) solutions for what I think is a well specified and fairly standard visualization problem, decided to quickly implement it myself. But before doing this, though, I wanted to get a sanity advice from the community.

I need to visualize a very specific kind of graph (this is why I don't wanna deal with any of those force-directed generic layouts that are hard to read), which seems like a version of a multipartite graph for the GraphPlan planning algorithm.

For those unfamiliar, a typical layout is essentially the same as that of a multi-layer neural net:
[image]

For simplicity, I am only considering even-numbered layers (since odd ones will essentially become edge labels)

At this point it is sufficient to represent colums of nodes simply as a table with *tabulate*. The only catch is that I need the backpointers (that is edges) also.

I am thinking in the direction of matplotlib's grid but would prefer not to go too low-level. I just need to connect arbitrary items, from *strictly* adjacent columns in this grid, after all. Pretty simple, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out not too terrible:
[image]

Basically:

1. Stored my objects in a 2d array
2. Generated Xs and Ys for a scatter plot grid (some additional care was needed to handle variable column height via the `zip(*izip_longest(*my2darray))` trick)
3. Iterated over my 2d array elements to pull out their labels
4. For each of them also drew line segments to each of their children from the previous column.